# Boolean difference not taking effect

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

I'm a blender novice trying to use the boolean difference tool to remove part of an object using another object extruded from an SVG, and while I've followed the steps detailed in a number of tutorials the modifier never seems to take effect, as per the screenshot. Any assistance with how I may be incorrectly using this modifier would be appreciated!

[Blend file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BpeewPjb1DGfI4nOXjpqfaHgrsehktOr/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: maybe you need to make the boolean object transparent, or try Solver > Fast instead of Exact, or please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That boolean has worked correctly but you need to hide it to see its effect. Select the boolean object (<kbd>pumpkininterface.svg</kbd>) then hit <kbd>H</kbd> and you'll see it has cut the pumpkin correctly. (Use <kbd>Alt-H</kbd> to unhide it.) If you want to make its effect permanent, select the pumpkin then apply the modifier by hovering over it on the modifier properties panel and hitting <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>. Then select and delete the boolean object using <kbd>X</kbd>.

[image]